# Jqgrid Keeps on loading

Tags: jqgrid

My `jqGrid` is displayed but it does'nt show the data I checked the json source and it is ok

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid(
    {
        url: 'GetDepartment',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Department ID', 'Department Name'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'DepartmentID', index: 'DepartmentID' },
            { name: 'DepartmentName', index: 'DepartmentName'}
        ],
        pager: $("#GridPager"),
        rowNum: 2,
        rowList: [5, 10, 15, 20],
        width: 'auto',
        sortname: 'DepartmentID',
        sortorder: "ASC"
    })
    $("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#GridPager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false})
})
```

Comment: How did you check that the Json was ok?  If you go to `GetDepartment` url you get back properly formatted Json data?

Comment: I use Fiddler for checking it return the proper json data format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing jsonReader, add the below code to your grid

```
            jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false
            id: "DepartmentID"

        },
```

Take a look at the wiki for json format expected

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data

so in your case the json response should be

```
{  "rows":[{"DepartmentID":2,"DepartmentName":"Asset Mgmt Group "},{"DepartmentID":16,"DepartmentName":"Business Solutions Group"},{"DepartmentID":8,"DepartmentName":"CBMG"}] }
```